# For random $x,y$ in (0,1) find $P(x+y<1)$

Tags: probability

Given two random numbers, $0<x \le y<1$ find the probability that the sum $x+y$ is less than $1$.

My gut feeling is that the answer is $\frac 12$, but I am looking for a concrete proof of such.

Comment: Draw a careful picture, including the lines $y=x$ and $x+y=1$. The joint density lives in the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why did someone just delete my comment?  I was asking an honest question about this post.

Comment: @pgmath on this site,  you are expected to show your own work on the problem and not only ask the question. That way we filter out zero effort questions that people ask when  they are too lazy to do their own homework.

Comment: @5xum  OK, I didn't realize that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $P(x + y = 1) = 0$ so by symmetry you have $P(x + y < 1) = P( X + Y > 1) = 1 - P(X + Y < 1)$.

Comment: Isn't the interesting part to show that $P(X+Y < 1) = P(X+Y > 1)$?  @PGmath: That happens to be true in this case (provided $(X, Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the lower right half of the unit square), but your complete answer should show this.

Comment: I agree with Brian Tung, this answer completely obscures the calculation by hiding it into an equality that is not explained: $P(x+x<1) = P(x+y > 1). Saying "this is true by symmetry" is not good enough, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of two random variables has a density which is the convolution of the individual densities. So you want to calculate the area integral of the triangle of this convolution. Individually they are uniform in one dimension and dirac distributions in the other. So that convolution will be a constant 1 square on $x\in[0,1], y\in[0,1]$. What remains is to decide the triangle. A little investigation on André Nicolas comment shows that it cuts the square exactly in half which gives 50%.